# How do I uninstall Office Live Add-in 1.4 after installing Office 2010?

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office-2010, office-live

Last night I upgraded to Office 2010 RTM from MSDN.

I'm now trying to uninstall the Office Live Add-in that I used with Office 2007 as this functionality is built in to Office 2010.

When I run the uninstall from control panel I get the following message:

> Microsoft Office Live Add-in cannot be installed because you do not have the right version of Microsoft Office installed on your computer

Google has pointed to 2 solutions, both of which are pretty useless:

1. [Use the MS Windows Installer Cleanup](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeinstall/thread/b54b52ab-b08e-4d01-a475-0eeb281223b4) - this is not good because all it does is remove the Installer entry from the registry, leaving all the installed files behind
2. [Uninstall Office 2010, uninstall Add-in, reinstall Office 2010](http://ask.officelive.com/workspace/qna/t/10198.aspx) - that is just ridiculous, but typical MS response

So, can I get this off my system without resorting to option 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it! [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx) was the answer.

I used [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) filtering on `msiexec.exe` for `Process Name` and `msi` for `Path`

[image]

This showed the correct .msi file to be `c:\windows\installer\b2cbf2.msi` (YMMV)

I opened this in Orca, searched for the error message and dropped each row which referred to it.

I save the file back to `c:\windows\installer` (Important! I tried it from desktop at first and it still accessed the one in `c:\windows\installer`, probably some GUID causing this).

This ran fine and the Add-in is now uninstalled!

Comment: Great solution, thanks. I wanted to add that the link to Orca refers to a Microsoft page which refers to another MS page which 404's. I needed to get the Windows 7 SDK, so I searched for that. I didn't want to install the whole thing, I just wanted Orca.msi, so I got the ISO version of the SDK, mounted it, expanded the Setup\WinSDKTools\cab1.cab, found Orca in there, and renamed it to Orca.msi and installed it. I then had to find Orca in Program Files x86, and run as Administrator. The only row that needed deleting is LaunchCondition.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Use the registry editor to rename

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0 (on a 32bit OS) or
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0 (on a 64bit OS)

   to

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\hide_14.0 (on a 32bit OS) or
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\hide_14.0 (on a 64bit OS)

   (the "hide_" can be any other text)
2. Run the uninstaller
3. Rename "hide_14.0" back to "14.0"

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, #2 is probably your best bet. The problem is that the uninstallers no longer see Office 2007 and are throwing the error.

I agree that it is completely ridiculous that you'd have to do this, but it is honestly probably your best bet.